# How to turn off matplotlib plot default axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting N plots in a grid without any decoration. The plots that have data are easily set to not show the axis by using axis('off'). But how can i do this for the "spillover" defaults from subplots()?

Here is a working example of the code in question:

```
import math

filenames = ['plot0', 'plot1', 'plot2', 'plot4', 'plot5', 'plot6', 'plot7', 'plot8', 'plot9', 'plotl0']

N = len(filenames)
Y = int(math.sqrt(N))
X = int(N / Y) + 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(X, Y)

for i in range(N):
    ax[divmod(i, Y)].text(0.5, 0.5, str('Test'))
    ax[divmod(i, Y)].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: A picture is worth 1000 words]

Comment: `for ax_i in np.ravel(ax): ax_i.axis('off')` ?

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why it works as opposed to my approach within the loop? Isn't your's just basically a different loop over the same?

Comment: You created all the axes to fill all the rows and columns. But usually N is less than the number of axes. For example N=10, X=4, Y=3 has 12 axes and only 10 plots. You also need to turn off the default axes for the last two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'add_subplot()' to add 'subplot' to the 'fig' object with the required graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

filenames = ['plot0', 'plot1', 'plot2', 'plot4', 'plot5', 'plot6', 'plot7', 'plot8', 'plot9', 'plotl0']

N = len(filenames)
Y = int(math.sqrt(N))
X = int(N / Y) + 1

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(1,N+1):
    axes.append(fig.add_subplot(X, Y, i))
    axes[i-1].text(0.5, 0.5, str('Test'))
    axes[i-1].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Marking that as answer since it's the only answer and works as well as the one above  in the comments. Once i figured out that i need to initialize the list :)

Comment: One easy way is to follow all calls to plt.subplots with the following line `[a.axis('off') for a in ax.ravel()]`. Easy one-liner.